# How can I block request thats come out from iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, server

F.e. I have such code

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="iframe.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

iframe.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            $.get("http://badsite.com");
            $.get("http://goodsite.com");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see iframe make two request and how can I block requests to http://badsite.com 
What I need to use js, php, or should configure my server or change my .htaccess file?

Comment: Why are you looking to do that? What are you *exactly* trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to block ads thats load into iframe

Comment: @АрыстанКалиакпаров — Loading other people's content on to your own website while stripping out their adverts has really nasty legal and ethical implications. Don't.

Comment: I am doing for personal use. I am trying to blocking ad because of it contains link to virus site

Comment: If you're doing it for personal use, then use a browser extension like Ghostery or Adblock Plus.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5 introduces [the sandbox attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) on the `iframe` that, disables JavaScript loading and execution.

Comment: @Quentin , sample `iframe` code contains only AJAX requests, so this solution suits well for example ;)

Comment: It contains **two** Ajax requests and the OP asked how to block **one** of them.

Comment: @Quentin , hm, you are right... that is difficult to do

Answer (score 0):

Set up a [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) with [`connect-src`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/connect-src).

You can't block badsite specifically, but you can allow only goodsite (or a list of sites that includes goodsite).

Your HTTP response headers for `iframe.html` should include:

```
Content-Security-Policy: connect-src http://goodsite.com http://different-goodsite.com
```

You could also use a meta element.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="connect-src http://goodsite.com http://different-goodsite.com">
```

Comment: Can I do it without changing iframe?

Comment: @АрыстанКалиакпаров - I don't think so