# How can i abort/cancel a HTTP request caused by Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I have this code to get a captcha from [this website](https://www2.inscription.tn/ORegMx/servlet/AuthentificationEtud?ident=cin)

```js
var imported = document.createElement('script');
imported.onload = function() {
  var str = document.querySelector("body > table.troisbords > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td > div > blockquote > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(3) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(1)").innerHTML.length
  if (str <= 43) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = "divPage";
    var img = document.querySelector("body > table.troisbords > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td > div > blockquote > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(3) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(1) > img");
    img.parentNode.insertBefore(div, img);
    div.appendChild(img);
  }

  html2canvas(document.querySelector("#divPage"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      var w = canvas.width;
      var h = canvas.height;
      ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF";
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
      var cap = document.querySelector("#divPage > img")
      ctx.drawImage(cap, 0, 0);
      var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/webp', 1.0);
      console.log(imgData);
    },
    useCORS: true,
    allowTaint: true,
    taintTest: false
  });
}

imported.src = 'https://pastebin.com/raw/dRap1YD8';
document.head.appendChild(imported);
```

This line send an img request to the server that cause changing of the captcha value

```
ctx.drawImage(cap,0,0);
```

I tried to use `XMLHttpRequest.abort()` but didn't work

Note that I'm using the Chrome console. I appreciate any help!

Comment: @JaromandaX but when i block the request in google chrome in the network tab, it work, it gives the captcha image without changing the value, that's why i think it's possible, with block it and unblock it if the captcha that the user entered is wrong so the server can send a new captcha then block it before running the js code

Comment: also pastebin is just temporary, i will use local lib in the final code

Comment: The browser itself allows deeper access to network traffic through dev tools, hence it's possible to do what you mention there. However it is not possible to achieve the same in JS directly.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan what about jquery or other js lib that can do that ?

Comment: No. Libraries are just an abstraction. If the underlying JS cannot do it, then they can't either.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can i change in the html like iframe this line `<img src="/ORegMx/capito.png" alt="capito">`  ,this is the line that cause the request i think, so it will stop the request ?  check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54256101/how-can-i-block-request-thats-come-out-from-iframe

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan note: i'm not the owner of the website

Comment: @JaromandaX that's why i said unblock it when the value of the captcha entered by the user is wrong

Comment: @JaromandaX how the cache works? can i get the image from the browser cache ? in chromium

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan trust me, i never give up, i asked before to how to get a captcha image in android webview, and everyone said, you can't it's impossible, and i did it with 1% knowladge in js, so, i will keep searching and i hope someone can help with anything

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan didn't understand what you mean by " doing far more productive things.", i'm working on an android app that give the results for students in my country, so i'm using webview to sendkeys... but the captcha when i thought i finished working on it, i wasn't able to connect to my account, so i find out about the requests when i tried it in chrome console, so i think this is a very productive thing to work on it, it's my first android app btw, and the gov doesn't have app like that, also it was a request from my colleagues

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how this worked but i add ?=0 after /ORegMx/capito.png using

```
document.querySelector("body > table.troisbords > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td > div > blockquote > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(3) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(1) > img").src="/ORegMx/capito.png?=0"
```